# object not found in filtering

Tags: r, object, filter, na

Hi I have a dataset called data I need to filter it here is my code

```
data_filtered <-  filter(data, Item !="INFUSION SET (L.E 15)" )
data_filtered <-  filter(data, Item !="INFUSION SET (L.E 4)"  )
data_filtered <-  filter(data, Item !="SYRINGE 3ML"  )
data_filtered <-  filter(data, Item !="CANNULA (22) BLUE")
```

I keep getting the error "NAs introduced by coercionError in filter(data2, Item != "INFUSION SET (L.E 15)") : 
  object 'Item' not found"

[image: this is the image of my dataset]

Comment: Which `filter` are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Edward mentioned you are probably using `stats::filter`. We can reproduce the same error message using sample `mtcars` dataset.

```
stats::filter(mtcars, cyl > 12)
```

> Error in stats::filter(mtcars, cyl > 12) : object 'cyl' not found

Use `dplyr::filter` and you don't need to specify four conditions separately. Use :

```
data_filtered <- dplyr::filter(data, !Item %in% c("INFUSION SET (L.E 15)",
                "INFUSION SET (L.E 4)","SYRINGE 3ML","CANNULA (22) BLUE"))
```

which is same as using `subset` in base R:

```
data_filtered <- subset(data, !Item %in% c("INFUSION SET (L.E 15)",
    "INFUSION SET (L.E 4)","SYRINGE 3ML","CANNULA (22) BLUE"))
```

Or

```
data_filtered <- data[!data$Item %in% c("INFUSION SET (L.E 15)",
           "INFUSION SET (L.E 4)","SYRINGE 3ML","CANNULA (22) BLUE"), ]
```